# syntax error ruby rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Hi for the life of me I cannot locate a syntax error in my rspec file.  I've gone over it dozens of times and just can't find it.  I could use an extra set of eyes to help me on this.  Heres my spec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  let(:user) { User.create!(name: "Bloccit User", email: "user@bloccit.com", 
  password: "password") }

  #name tests
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_length_of(:name).is_at_least(1) }

  #email tests
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:email) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:email) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_length_of(:email).is_at_least(3) }
  it { is_expected.to allow_value("user@bloccit.com").for(:email) }

  #password tests
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:password) }
  it { is_expected.to have_secure_password }
  it { is_expected.to validate_length_of(:password).is_at_least(6)}

  describe "attributes" do
    it "should have a name and an email address" do
     expect(user).to have_attributes(name: "Bloccit User", email: 
     "user@bloccit.com")
    end

    it "should capitalize the user name" do
     user.name = 'bloc user'
     user.save
     expect(user.name).to eq "Bloc User"
    end
  end

  describe "invalid user" do
   let(:user_with_invalid_name) {User.new(name: "", 
     email:"user@bloccit.com")}
   let(:user_with_invalid_email) {User.new(name: "Bloccit User", email:"")}

   it "should have an invalid user due to blank name" do
     expect(user_with_invalid_name).to_not be_valid
   end

   it "should be an invalid user due to blank email" do
     expect(user_with_invalid_email).to_not be_valid
   end

  end
 end
```

I get the following error every time I run the code.

```
SyntaxError:
 /mnt/c/Users/bjm84/Bloccit/app/models/user.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected 
 end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

If someone could help me pinpoint this I would appreciate it.  This has miffed me pretty good.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that the syntax error is in line 26 of your *User model file*.

```
/mnt/c/Users/bjm84/Bloccit/app/models/user.rb:26
```

It's not in the spec file.